# Unexpected token I in JSON at position 0 while using fetch in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, fetch-api

I am trying to fetch an API of login. The API is working fine on the Backend server, but as soon as I try to use the API from the frontend side, it shows the error:

> Unexpected token I in JSON at position 0.

Below is the code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const LoginPage = (props) => {

let navigate = useNavigate();

const [credentials, setCredentials] = useState({email:"",password:""});


const onChange = (e) => {
    setCredentials({ ...credentials, [e.target.name]: [e.target.value]})
    //  console.log(credentials);
}


const handleSubmit = async(e) => {

    e.preventDefault();
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/login", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        email: credentials.email,
        password: credentials.password,
      }),
    });
    const json = await response.json();
    console.log(json)

    
}

const goToSignUp = () => {
   navigate("/signup");
}


  return (
    <>
  <div className="container my-5">
    <div id="loginbody">
      <div className="mt-3">
        <h2 className="my-3 display-3">Login Here</h2>
        <form className="login-form p-5" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <div className="mb-3">
            <label htmlFor="exampleInputEmail1" className="form-label">
              Email address
            </label>
            <input
              type="email"
              className="form-control"
              id="email"
              name="email"
              value={credentials.email}
              aria-describedby="emailHelp"
              onChange={onChange}
            />
            <div id="emailHelp" className="form-text">
              We'll never share your email with anyone else.
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="mb-3">
            <label htmlFor="exampleInputPassword1" className="form-label">
              Password
            </label>
            <input
              type="password"
              className="form-control"
              id="password"
              name="password"
              value={credentials.password}
              onChange={onChange}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="d-grid gap-2 my-4 col-6 mx-auto">
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-success" >
            Submit
          </button>
          </div>
          <hr />
        <div className="mb-3 text-center">
          <div id="emailHelp" className="form-text center my-3">
            Didn't have an account ?
          </div>
          <div className="d-grid gap-2 my-3 col-6 mx-auto">
            <button onClick={goToSignUp} className="btn btn-success ">
              SignUp Here !
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</>
);
};

export default LoginPage;
```

Here is the screen showing error in the first line of `handleSUbmit()` function.

[image: error image]

Also my API response:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "authToken": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyIjp7ImlkIjoiNjFiMzZlNGVmYTI5MWU1YjdlNWQzZTEwIn0sImlhdCI6MTYzOTI3NDgwMn0.p-Rh_yNe4N-sFZ0G_z7o76FXV9GyFx85xN7A424t9cI",
    "user": {
        "_id": "61b36e4efa291e5b7e5d3e10",
        "name": "Mayank Maroliya",
        "email": "mayank1@test.com",
        "password": "$2a$10$BThh1HeUuhyFBmVc8YzPO.JILhPJsS4sg18sPGe86HmlBjh0svTmi",
        "role": "guest",
        "forgetQues": "Favourite Sport",
        "forgetAns": "Chess",
        "__v": 0
    }
}
```

Can I get help?

Comment: can you try like this> body: {
        email: credentials.email,
        password: credentials.password,
      },

Comment: I used `body: {
        email: credentials.email,
        password: credentials.password,
      },`
it is showing `Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue, I am passing both the `email` as object in the `onChange` function.It should be `String`.

Incorrect Code:

```
setCredentials({ ...credentials, [e.target.name]: [e.target.value]})
```

Corrected Code:

```
setCredentials({ ...credentials, [e.target.name]: e.target.value})
```